# switch statement in for loop and if statement not completing

Tags: javascript, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm trying to find out how many of each character are in a string.

I've searched around for a while and can't seem to figure out why my switch statement is stopping after the first case.

```
function charFreq(string){
    var splitUp = string.split("");
    console.log(splitUp);
    var a;
    var b;
    var c;
    var v;

    for (var i = 0; i<splitUp.length; i++){
        if (i<1){
            switch (splitUp[i]){
                case "a":
                 a = 1;
                break;
                case "b":
                 b = 1;
                break;
                case "c":
                 c = 1;
                break;
                case "v":
                 v = 1;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            switch (splitUp[i]){
                case "a":
                 a += 1;
                break;
                case "b":
                 b += 1;
                break;
                case "c":
                 c += 1;
                break;
                case "v":
                 v += 1;
                break;
            }
        } 
    } 
    console.log("There are " + a + " A's, " + b + " B's, " + c + " C's, and " + v + " V's.")
}

charFreq("aaabccbbavabac");
```

What am I doing wrong that would make the console read:

> There are 6 A's, NaN B's, NaN C's, and NaN V's.

Comment: What language is this? Please add a tag.

Comment: javascript, if I had to guess

Comment: why do you have to split up the string, why not pass through it and iterate counters?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that variables (`a`, `b`, `c` and `v`) are not initialized. The for loop iterates through the characters, but only the first iteration assigns an initial value to one of the variables (which equals to the character). The rest of the loop tries increase the value of those variables by 1, but most of them (except one) are undefined. So to fix your code, assign an initial value to the variables:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var v = 0;
```

And then you can simplify your for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < splitUp.length; i++) {
    switch (splitUp[i]) {
    case "a":
        a += 1;
        break;
    case "b":
        b += 1;
        break;
    case "c":
        c += 1;
        break;
    case "v":
        v += 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

But counting characters this way is just too complicated. You can use a much simpler code, for example:

```
var str = "teststring";
var chars = [];

str.split('').map(function(char) {
  chars[char] = (chars[char] === undefined) ? 1 : chars[char] + 1;
});

console.log(chars); // [t: 3, e: 1, s: 2, r: 1, i: 1…]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are superflous if you would initialize all your variables. It breaks your logic because you are only assigning one number based on if the index is on the first character.